Geometry nodes - How to Knife project procedurally
Is it possibple to knife project in geometry nodes procedurally? Like knife project tool

Expanding on @Bicukow's answer just a bit, I added a part to allow you to rotate and aim the cutter object as you like. I also think this way is a bit cleaner for getting the intersection with more complex geo, the one-mesh boolean method caused some weird triangulation. It did however subvert the interior face issue so... shrugs

Either way it's a bit fiddly but it works.




Geometry node setup is pretty funky, but its working through boolean node (difference), but you actually need to join both mesh and extruded curve before using and leave second slot of boolean node empty, then just delete faces of extruded mesh using attribute capture node before boolean. ¯_(ツ)_/¯
Note: This is the stablest way to knife project, but on complex geometry it will triangulate faces, that will be cutted.


